# Dispalying sonar widget according to the technology

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have created a dummy widget and its displayed in the sonar dasboard after configuring the widget. Now the widget is displayed in every project. How can I show the widget for a specific technology(like objc) and hide it for other technologies?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible ( filtering-out widgets based to a language ). I'd suggest that you create different dashboards instead.

Comment: And here is the relating JIRA ticket : http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-3390